# How to remove additional image from the end with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am displaying data with ng repeat and seperating each data with 1 image.Now i have different sections(i.e td) for `data rendering and image displaying`.

Now the problem is that my image is displaying at the last which i dont want.

**Current Behaviour:[image]**

**Code:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
           <tr>
              <td align="center" ng-repeat-start="item in data">
                           <div>{{ item.Name }}</div>
               </td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle" ng-repeat-end>
                          <img src="~/images/LineSeperator.png">
                 </td>
           </tr>
</table>
```

How to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`$last`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

```
ng-if="!$last"
```

Comment: Yeah it works.thank you so much for your kind help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help

```
<style>
  table td:last-child {
    display:none;
  }
</style>
```